# Limit Comparison Test with upside-down division

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital, divergent-series

I have a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt[2019]{n+2020}}{n^2-2020}$ and I'm looking for a series that converges in order to use the Limit Comparison Test, such as: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n} = \frac{1}{n^2}$ , 
 would that be ok to use the  test while dividing upside-down?

Usually the explanations about the test require that I devide the series$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ that  I have by the one I call $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$, and finding if
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}\rightarrow k$ , whereas $0<k<\infty.$

Assuming THERE IS suck k, then the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}}$ should be $\frac{1}{k}$ by arithmetics, and in case k is not $0$ nor $\infty$,  can I rely on arithmetics and use this limit as well and make conclusions based on the comparison test, can't I?

Suppose I need to use the Limit Comparison Test to decide if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ coverges , am I restricted only to the form of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$ , or the assumptions that I made were eligible and I can use the upside-down version as well?

Comment: It doesn't matter much whether you take the limit of $a_n/b_n$ or of $b_n/a_n$. In this example, I wouldn't choose $b_n=1/n^2$ though.

Comment: It's the first series that came to mind that converges, but it was just an example though. The more important thing was to be able to assume I can take this test either way :)

Comment: Im kind of stuck, do you have any suggestion which series is a good pick for the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it does not matter if you divide them in the other direction.

Proof: Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=k$, where $0 \lt k \lt \infty$. Note that since the sequence $A=(a_n), B=(b_n)$ are greter than $0 $ (strictly).

Consider the sequence $C=(\dfrac{a_n}{b_n} \cdot \dfrac{b_n}{a_n})=(1)$, which converges to $1$.

By limit theorem, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}}$ exists and equal $(lim (1))/\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=1/k$. Which is again strictly greater than $0$, and finite.

Hence it happens that  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=k$, where $0 \lt k \lt \infty$ iff   $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}}=1/k$ where $0 \lt 1/k \lt \infty$.

Secondly, for a good series to solve the problem, consider $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n} = \frac{ ^{2019}\sqrt{x}}{n^2}$.

Note that since $a_n$ are not positive in the first few terms ($\lfloor 
\sqrt(2200) \rfloor$ terms), truncate it such that all terms are positive, hence condition of limit comparison test is fulfilled.

Comment: thank you for the informative proof of the first part! :)
the series you offered for the test is quite good with the justification the there is an index n from which the series is positive.
Ultimately I get a $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=1$ but I figured out another way to solve it using the fact that both parts of the fraction act like a polynomial with rank 'r' and if $r_{2}-r_{1}> 1$ the series converges